# Как правильнее транслитерировать/перевести имя Jian-Yang?

Tags: перевод, транслитерация, выбор-имени

Как правильнее транслитерировать/перевести имя Jian-Yang ? (персонаж из "Silicon Valley")

Comment: Бахман называет его Джинь-янь (как-то так).

Comment: здесь имя указано с тонами (4-й и 2-й)  http://silicon-valley.wikia.com/wiki/J%C3%ACng-Y%C3%A1ng

Comment: из этих текстов [1](http://global.sina.cn/szzx/article/20180401/02c7599584051000.html), [2](http://t.cj.sina.com.cn/articles/view/6480039314/1823d8d92001007a9p), [3](http://vr.pconline.com.cn/1018/10188864.html)  следует, что китайцы тоже не знают, как это имя пишется иероглифами, так как авторы обозначают его латиницей

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если это пиньинь, а похоже на то, тогда

**Цзянь Ян**, если это фамилия и имя, или

**Цзяньян**, если это имя

Подкрепляя цитатой из [таблицы перевода пиньиня в систему Палладия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83_%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F)

> jian — цзянь
>
> yang — ян

Comment: можно ли по пиньинь восстановить иероглифы, и затем перевести уже их? Если ли альтернативы пиньинь и системе Палладия?

Comment: @yalov подозреваю, что человек, хорошо владеющий китайским и знакомый с конвенциями китайских имён может попробовать с некоторой долей вероятности угадать, задачу облегчило бы знание какими тонами произносятся эти слова или что они означают в имени, но перевести их в иероглифы наверняка невозможно... системе пиньинь [есть альтернативы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanization_of_Chinese#Non-Chinese_systems), ныне мало употребимые, а системе Палладия нет

Comment: @yalov здесь есть [форум китайского языка](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/), попробуйте справиться там

Comment: @yalov [Нельзя](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8_%D0%A8%D0%B8_%D1%88%D0%B8_%D1%88%D0%B8_%D1%88%D0%B8)

Answer (score 3):

As for the question in comments: not too many versions to guess the name meaning. Some real people with such a name/surname are written in Chinese as 杨健 (Yáng Jiàn, 2nd and 4th tones). The first character is known to be used as a surname (dictionaries say so), but it also has the meaning '**poplar**'; the second character means '**healthy/strong**'. Examples from wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang_Jian_(footballer) ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang_Jian_(diver) .

If a person of Chinese origin lives in a Western country, the original surname+name order is often *reversed* into name+surname: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jian_Yang_(politician) - same could be with the film character.

There were also historical Yang Jian persons with the surname 杨 who had different name part 暕 (Jian, 3rd tone - **bright/light**) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang_Jian_(Sui_prince) and 堅 (Jian, 1st tone, **strong**) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emperor_Wen_of_Sui .

Comment: there in the end of https://youtu.be/Qe3tPNUAF7g?t=1m19s I hear "Чинь-янь". Is there some system corresponds or explains this "Чинь-янь" vs Цзянь Ян ?

Comment: @yalov среднестатистические англофоны естественно не знают как правильно произносить звуки китайского языка в транскрипции пиньинь, поэтому произносят их как удобно, т.е. согласно фонетике английского... это не критично для расшифровки имени, но стоит указать, что в именах в вышеприведённых ссылках на Википедию слова находятся в обратном порядке по отношению к искомому имени, т.е. фамилия Yang, а имя Jian (при условии что в имени Jian-Yang они находятся в правильном порядке, т.е. сначала фамилия, как принято у китайцев, а затем имя)

Comment: Neither Russian (Palladium) transcription nor pinyin one mean that reading using Russian or English rules would give proper sound of Mandarin Chinese. Pinyin has reading rules different from English. So it doesn't matter how English speakers pronounce Chinese names, correctly written in pinyin. Also, there might be some influence of the fact that the actor playing Jian-Yang is of Hong-Kong origin (Cantonese is different from Mandarin) while his character's name is not Cantonese. Despite the formal Russian transcription is **цзянь**, it actually sounds closer to **дьзиЭн** in Chinese.

Comment: @yalov из [этого текста](http://siliconvalleyism.com/silicon-valley-jian-yang-quotes.php) понятно, что Цзянь - это фамилия, то есть порядок слов в имени соответствует китайскому